# How to compare two reals based on lexicographic ordering of their decimal representation

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

Let $$x = m + 0.d_1 d_2 \cdots, \qquad y = n + 0.e_1 e_2 \cdots$$ be real numbers. Give a rule for determining whether $x = y, x < y$ or $x > y$, based on the decimal representation.

Comment: I have tried a number of ideas but got stuck somewhere every time. Please provide your insights to help me sort this question out.

Comment: Here's a few examples to get you started.  Which is bigger?  $5.7$ or $6.2$?  Try to explain in words why the one is bigger than the other.  Next, how about $1.33$ versus $1.315$?  Which is bigger?  Adding even more digits... $3.13372515$ versus $3.13372518$, which is bigger?  Now, the only thing which should actually make this a challenge... which is bigger?  $1.0$ or $0.99999\dots$?

Comment: Adding color to make it hopefully more obvious... $\color{blue}{5}.7 < \color{red}{6}.2$... also $\color{grey}{1.3}\color{red}{3}>\color{grey}{1.3}\color{blue}{1}5$, and similarly $\color{grey}{3.1337251}\color{blue}{5}<\color{grey}{3.1337251}\color{red}{8}$.

Comment: The keyword is **lexicographic ordering**

Comment: I have taken the liberty to change your very neutral title "How would you solve this" into something that is likely to attract much more people ...

Comment: @JeanMarie Thanks for that.